# Issues with basic JavaScript/HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

Something is stopping the "compute Payment" button from showing up. I did a very similar problem earlier and used a similar line of code for making the button show up, so I am confused why it isnt working now. Also, have a few errors that I can't figure out, professor is unresponsive.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title> Internet Service Costs </title>

<script>
function computeAmtDue(){
    var amountDue;


    if (document.getElementById(‘Year10’).checked){
        amountDue = 12.95 +((document.getElementById(‘hours’) - 10) * 4.00);
    if (document.getElementById(‘Nonprofit’).checked){
        amountDue *=.80;
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    }
} else if (document.getElementById(‘Year20’).checked) {
    amountDue = 14.95 +((document.getElementById(‘hours’) - 20) * 2.00);
    if (document.getElementById(‘Nonprofit’).checked){
        amountDue *=.80;
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    }
} else if (document.getElementById(‘Year30’).checked){
    amountDue = 20.00 +((document.getElementById(‘hours’) - 30) * 1.00);
    if (document.getElementById(‘Nonprofit’).checked){
        amountDue *=.80;
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    }   
} else if (document.getElementById(‘YearUnl’).checked){
    amountDue = 35.95;
    if (document.getElementById(‘Nonprofit’).checked){
        amountDue *=.80;
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    }
    }
}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Internet Service Costs </h1>

<form name=“InternetPmt”>

  <input type="radio" name=“Package” value="10" id=“Year10” />Package A<br>
  <input type="radio" name=“Package” value=“20” id=“Year20” />Package B<br>
  <input type="radio" name=“Package” value="30" id=“Year30” />Package C<br>
  <input type="radio" name=“Package” value=""  id=“YearUnl” />Package D<br>
<br>

  <input type="checkbox" name=“NonprofitOrg” value=“Nonprofit“ id=“Nonprofit”> 
Nonprofit Organization<br>

  <p> Hours Used:<input type="text" name=“Hours” value="" id=“hours” /> </p>

  Total Amount Due:
  <input type=“text” name=“AmtDue” value="" /><br><br>
  <input type=“button” value=“Compute Monthly” name=“btnCompute” 
onclick=“computeAmtDue()”/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The console responses though ...

Comment: ^ learn to use the console, you do have syntax errors.

Comment: Can you turn this up in a quick plunker..

Comment: The single-quotes you're using are... not single-quotes.  This is why word processors make terrible IDEs.

Comment: I changed my single-quotes to double-quotes and I also used the console, which told me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" for line 11. I can't figure out the errors, so I was hoping someone would be able to help me figure them out. My professor hasn't been very good with being responsive outside of class.

Comment: Single- and double-quotes are both fine for JavaScript and HTML, but smart/curly quotes are not. That is, you want `'` or `"`, not `‘` and `’` or `“` and `”`. Fix all of those in your JavaScript *and* in your HTML and then try again. Don't use a word processor - if you don't have some other IDE then use Notepad (if you're on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

replace your all `‘ ’` with `' '` and `‘‘ ’’` with `" "` and you forget to add `.value` after `getElementById` check it, it works.

```js
function computeAmtDue(){
    var amountDue;

    if (document.getElementById('Year10').checked){
        amountDue = 12.95 +((document.getElementById('hours').value - 10) * 4.00);
    if (document.getElementById('Nonprofit').checked){
        amountDue *=.80;
        console.log(amountDue);
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
        console.log(amountDue);
    }
} else if (document.getElementById('Year20').checked) {
    amountDue = 14.95 +((document.getElementById('hours').value - 20) * 2.00);
    if (document.getElementById('Nonprofit').checked){
        amountDue *=.80;
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    }
} else if (document.getElementById('Year30').checked){
    amountDue = 20.00 +((document.getElementById('hours').value - 30) * 1.00);
    if (document.getElementById('Nonprofit').checked){
        amountDue *=.80;
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    }   
} else if (document.getElementById('YearUnl').checked){
    amountDue = 35.95;
    if (document.getElementById('Nonprofit').checked){
        amountDue *=.80;
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    } else {
        document.InternetPmt.AmtDue.value = amountDue.toFixed(2);
    }
    }
}
```

```html
<h1> Internet Service Costs </h1>

<form name="InternetPmt">

  <input type="radio" name="Package" value="10" id="Year10" />Package A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Package" value="20" id="Year20" />Package B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Package" value="30" id="Year30" />Package C<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Package" value=""  id="YearUnl" />Package D<br>
<br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="NonprofitOrg" value="Nonprofit" id="Nonprofit"> 
Nonprofit Organization<br>

  <p> Hours Used:<input type="text" name="Hours" value="" id="hours" /> </p>

  Total Amount Due:
  <input type="text" name="AmtDue" value="" /><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Compute Monthly" name="btnCompute" 
onclick="computeAmtDue()"/>

</form>
```